# Rails rescue_from Re-Raise Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a project where the previous developers added this to the application controller:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500
```

I presume that it was to catch this and render a dynamic page.  Static pages were not acceptable, but I am unsure now as to why that is.  In any case, this is messing up my ability to capture exceptions with Exceptional.  Is there any way to re-raise the exception after the dynamic error page has been rendered?

I tried this:

```
def rescue_from(exception)
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { #render the page# }
  end
  raise exception
end
```

However, that, quite obviously, does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could manually post to exceptional -- rather than try to re-raise and get Exceptional to catch and post.

```
def rescue_from(exception)
  ::Exceptional::Catcher.handle(exception)
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { #render the page# }
  end
end
```

Comment: I was just fixin' to say something similar :).

Comment: This works!  Thanks Jesse!  For anyone coming across this in the future, make sure that you enable Exceptional for your development environment, or this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do the raising of the exception in a begin or rescue and do the respond_to in an ensure?

I'm providing b) below because I'm not sure a) will work. Obviously you could cause any exception to be raised in the b) example to get into the rescue block and then raise the passed - in exception.

Either:

a)

```
begin
 raise exception
ensure
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { #render the page }
  end
end
```

OR

b)

```
begin
  raise exception
rescue Exception => e
  raise e
ensure
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { #render the page }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500

def rescue_500(exception)
    raise exception
end
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html), if this doesn't work, that should help you find a solution that does.

Comment: My mistake for not reading the question carefully enough. That being said, many people don't read the docs, and pointing them in that direction helps.